Characterization of reduced closed subschemes of a scheme

I'm proving the fact stated below in italics. I couldn't find a detailed proof anywhere, as it seems that it is a ordinary fact to check; the hint I managed to find suggested to reduce to the affine case, and then use gluing arguments. However I have some issues, mainly with the existence part, following this path; thus I tried to use a quotient scheme as construction, and use the universal property of quotients to prove uniqueness. Still, I have some issues with the right definition of the sheaf of ideals to use for the quotient. Here I expose my attempt.

Let $(X,O_X)$ be a scheme, and $Z\subset X$ a closed set. For later, let $X=\bigcup _k(X_k)$ be an affine open cover, $Z_k:=X_k\cap Z$, so that $Z=\bigcup _k(Z_k)$ is an open cover.
A structure of closed subscheme on $Z$ is a structure of scheme $(Z,O_Z)$ plus a closed immersion of schemes $$(i,i^\#):(Z,O_Z)\to(X,O_X),$$ where $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion.
Claim: there is exactly one structure of reduced closed subscheme on $Z$, modulo isomorphisms compatible with the structural closed immersions.
Before starting with the proof, we define a sheaf of ideals $N_{Z,X}$ over $O_X$: on any open set $U\subset X$, let $N_{Z,X}(U)$ be the ideal of sections $s\in O_X(U)$ such that $s_x\in \mathrm{nil}(O_{X,x})$ for all $x\in U\cap Z$. The construction of $N_{-,-}$ can be replied for any pair of scheme and closed subset, and it commutes with isomorphisms and restrictions of schemes.
We will also use these preliminary facts:
(1) Let $(i,i^\#):(Z,O_Z)\to(X,O_X)$ be a structure of closed subscheme on $Z$. There is a isomorphism of schemes from $(Z,O_Z)$ to $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X/\operatorname{ker}i^\#))$, which is compatible with the structural closed immersions.
(2) Let $\alpha:R\to R'$ be a morphism of ring sheaves over $X$. A sheaf of ideals $I$ over $R$ is the kernel of $\alpha$ if and only if the sheaf of ideals $I|_{X_k}$ over $R|_{X_k}$ is the kernel of $\alpha|_{X_k}$, for all $k$.
(3) Suppose that the scheme $(X,O_X)$ is affine, i.e. it is of the form $(\operatorname{Spec} A,O_A)$ for a ring $A$, and $Z=V(I)$ for a radical ideal $I\subset A$.  Then there is exactly one structure of reduced closed subscheme on $V(I)$, always modulo isomorphisms compatible with the structural closed immersions; such structure is given by the closed immersion $$(\operatorname{Spec}\pi,\pi^\#):(V(I),O_{A/I})\to(\operatorname{Spec} A,O_A),$$ where $\pi:A\to A/I$ is the projection.
We can begin the proof.
Set $N:=N_{Z,X}$ for convenience.
Let $(i,i^\#):(Z,O_Z)\to(X,O_X)$ be a structure of reduced closed subscheme on $Z$; we show that $N$ is the kernel of $i^\#$, so that 1 yields a isomorphism from $(Z,O_Z)$ to $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X/N)$. By the arbitrariness of the structure chosen on $Z$, and the isomorphism compatibility with the structures, it will follow that $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X/N)$ is the unique structure of reduced closed subscheme on $Z$.
So we show ($*$) that $N=\operatorname{ker}i^\#$.
By 2, it is enough to prove that the sheaf of ideals $N|_{X_k}$ over $O_X|_{X_k}$ is the kernel of $i^\#|_{X_k}$, for all $k$. But $i^\#|_{X_k}$ is part of a structure of closed subscheme on $Z_k$: $$(i|_{Z_k},i^\#|_{X_k}):(Z_k,O_Z|_{Z_k})\to(X_k,O_X|_{X_k}).$$ Also, $N_{Z_k,X_k}=N|_{X_i}$, and the scheme $(X_k,O_{X}|_{X_k})$ is affine. Hence proving that $N|_{X_k}$ is the kernel of $i^\#|_{X_k}$ is equivalent to prove ($*$) in the case that the scheme $(X,O_X)$ is affine.
So let $A$ be a ring and $(\operatorname{Spec}A,O_A)$ be an affine scheme. Fix a closed set $V(I)$, for a radical ideal $I\subset A$. Recalling 3, we must show that $N:=N_{V(I),\mathrm{Spec}A}$ is the kernel of $\pi^\#$.
The morphism of sheaves $$\pi^\#:O_A\to (\operatorname{Spec}\pi)_* (O_{A/I})$$ is defined on any principal open set $D_f$, with $f\in A$, by the canonical map $$\pi^\#(D_f):A_f\to (A/I)_{\bar f},$$ where $\bar f:=\pi(f)$. But $\operatorname{ker}\pi^\#(D_f)$ is known to be $I_f\subset A_f$, meaning that we must prove that $N(D_f)=I_f$ on any principal open set $D_f$. In fact, two sheaves (of modules, in general) coincide if their restrictions at all the open sets in an open cover coincide.
Now it comes to commutative algebra. Fixed $f\in A$, for any prime ideal $p\subset A$ such that $f\notin p$, let $\varphi_p:A_f\to A_p$ be the canonical map. We must prove this: given $s\in A_f$, one has $\varphi_p(s)\in \mathrm{nil}(A_p)$ for all prime ideals $p\subset A$, with $p\not\ni f$ and $p\supset I$, if and only if $s\in I_f$.
Note that the map $A_f\to A_p$ is also the localization of $A_f$ at the prime ideal $pA_f$. Plus, the ideals $pA_f$, with $p\not\ni f$ and $p\supset I$, are exactly the prime ideals $q\subset A_f$ with $q\supset I_f$, so we reduce to: given $s\in A$, one has $\varphi_p(s)\in \mathrm{nil}(A_p)$ for all prime ideals $I\subset p\subset A$ if and only if $s\in I$.
One implication is true: if some $a\in A$ satisfies $\varphi(a)\in \mathrm{nil}(A_p)$ for all prime ideals $I\subset p\subset A$, it surely holds that $a\in p$ for all such $p$, so $a\in \mathrm{rad}(I)=I$.

However the converse doesn't seem to hold; it looks like I should require that the images $\varphi_p(a)$ are nilpotent in $(A/I)_p$, but I would not know how to extend this definition in the non affine case. Plus I know from the material of my course that the right definition for $N$, when $Z=X$, is: $N(U)\subset O_X(U)$ is the ideal of elements $s$ such that $s_x\in\operatorname {nil}(O_{X,x})$ for all $x\in U$, so the definition for $N_{Z,X}$ shluld be a generalization of this case. I hope you have some suggestion, thank you for your patience.

